# Write bash array to file with newlines

Tags: arrays, bash

How do I write an array to a file such that each element is separated by a newline?

The following does not work:

```
testa=( 1 2 3 )
echo "${testa[@]}" > file.txt
```

(now the elements are separated by spaces on a single line)
I would like avoid writing a `for` loop for this...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use `printf` instead:

```
printf "%s\n" "${testa[@]}" > file.txt

cat file.txt 
1
2
3
```

Comment: To have one item per line I have to remove quotes: printf "%s\n" ${testa[@]} > file.txt

Comment: FYI, if you prefer one line per item, use quotes around `"${testa[@]}"` in gitbash.